# Clear GrantSendOnBehalfTo on a mailbox exchange - from remote powershell script

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

To revoke permissions for GrantSendOnBehalfTo  from a mailbox, it is pretty well documented, that you would do this:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity MyMailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo $null
```

That works when run from powershell and in a local script.

However, if I include it in a script, that runs remote powershell (using New-PSSession etc), it fails with this error:

> Couldn't find object "[Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter]". Please make sure that it was
>   spelled correctly or specify a different object.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : A32A9BAB

So it will not accept $null as a parameter.

How can I get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, especially if this was Office 365 with DirSync, the easiest way would be to leave the `publicDelegates` attribute empty in the AD.

Make sure to use the UPN for the identity (which isn't required if working with a single mailbox):

```
Set-Mailbox -identity xxx@something.com -grantSendOnBehalfTo $null
```

or

```
Set-Mailbox xxx@something.com -grantSendOnBehalfTo $null
```